# post array into mvc controller list from angularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs, ajax, asp.net-mvc, list

I have an array which looks like this

```
var saturday=["10/14/2018","10/21/2018","10/28/2018","11/04/2018","11/11/2018","11/18/2018","11/25/2018","12/02/2018"];
```

now I want to post this array into my mvc controller

I created one class

```
public class saturdays
{
    public string saturday { get; set; }
}
```

and one method

```
 public JsonResult insertAllHolidays(List<saturdays> saturday)
 {
     return null;
 }
```

and I am posting the data into controller like this

```
$http.get('/Main/insertAllHolidays', {
    params: {
        saturday: saturdayArray
    }
}).then(function (data) {

});
```

but I am getting the error of

> resource cannot be find
>
> The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could
>   have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily
>   unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is
>   spelled correctly.

how can I post my array int mvc list?

Comment: You cannot post an array to a GET method (unless its in the format `{ saturday: "10/14/2018", saturday: "10/21/2018", ....}` and then you change the method parameter to `List<string> saturday` (or better `List<DateTime> saturday`).

Comment: please can you explain this as an answer

Comment: Why do you want this as a GET rather than a POST? And in addition your url is calling `insertAllHolidays` but your method is named `insertSundays`

Comment: @StephenMuecke it was a typo, can you please help me with this?

Comment: I assume ` saturday: saturdayArray` is a typo as well (the variable is named `var saturday = [...]`? No time just now - will add answer in about an hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply pass in the list on the `params` as follows:

```
var app = angular.module("appModule", [])

app.controller("SomeController", function ($scope, $http) {

   $scope.sendData = function () {
      $http.get("home/insertAllHolidays", {
         params: {
            saturday: [
               "10/14/2018",
               "10/21/2018",
               "10/28/2018",
               "11/04/2018",
               "11/11/2018",
               "11/18/2018",
               "11/25/2018",
               "12/02/2018"
            ]
         }
      });
   }

});
```

And the corresponding method (in your case `insertAllHolidays`) on your controller should be able to pick this up.

**NOTE**: You might want to do `List<string> list` as the input parameter and do your date conversion to the `saturdays` class object.

More on the config arguments:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-arguments

Comment: I was able to get my breakpoint hit and the data correctly mapped to this `saturday` argument.